# how to close expandable menu with click outside div and js

Tags: javascript, menu

I created an expandable menu in js. I add the open class with the click event, and click again to remove that class.

I want to close the menu when i click outisde the menu. I tried with document.addEventListener but does not seem to work.

```
function collapse() {
    if (this.classList.contains('open')) {
        this.classList.remove('open');
        document.removeEventListener('click', collapse, false);
    } else {
        this.classList.add('open');
        document.addEventListener('click', collapse, false);
    }
}


var x = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-menu");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener('click', collapse, false);
}
```

Here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4cv220mc/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the code you posted closes the menu even when you click on one of the `li` elements in the menu - this would not be desirable surely, so it would be best to put a check on the target of the collapse event click and close/open only when the `h3` element of the menu is clicked on.

Second, what you are looking for here is the `event.stopPropagation` function. That way you can put event listeners on the `toggle-menu` class and also on `document.documentElement` - which would be the `html` element (you can put it on document.body but sometimes that doesn't fill the screen).

So the menu event listener would toggle the `open` class and stop further propagation. The html event listener - which would now only be called if the menu event listener was *not* called first - would check if there are any open menus and if so, would remove the `open` class from all of them.

This way you can have as many menus, and clicking anywhere outside any of an open menu (including another menu) closes it.

Here is the JS code for your jsFiddle (I used `[].slice.call` to convert all menu elements to an array so that I could call a forEach function on them, I find this easier to read/write, but your method of counter also works of course):

```
var html = document.documentElement,
    menus = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-menu'));

function menuClick(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()=='h3'){
        this.classList.toggle('open');
    }
    var openMenus = document.querySelectorAll('.open.toggle-menu');
    for(var i=0;i<openMenus.length;i++){
        if(openMenus[i]==this)
            continue;
        openMenus[i].classList.remove('open');
    }
}
function bodyClick(e){
    if(document.querySelector('.toggle-menu.open')){
        menus.forEach(function(menu){
            if(menu.classList.contains('open'))
                menu.classList.remove('open');
        });
    }
}
menus.forEach(function(menu){
    menu.addEventListener('click',menuClick,false);
});
html.addEventListener('click',bodyClick,false);
```

If you want to have menus simultaneously open (clicking one shouldn't close the others), you can remove the part starting from `var openMenus` in the `menuClick` function.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/811r0nzw/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="toggle-menu">

<h3 class="toggle-label">Menu</h3>

<ul class="toggle-body">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Css -

```
.toggle-menu {
background-color:#ccc;
}
.toggle-body {
    display:none;
}
.open .toggle-body {
    display:block;
}
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
}
```

JS -

```
    function collapse() {
    if (this.classList.contains('open')) {
        this.classList.remove('open');
        document.removeEventListener('click', collapse, false);
    } else {
        this.classList.add('open');
        document.addEventListener('click', collapse, false);
    }
}


var x = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-menu");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener('click', collapse, false);
}

var y = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper");
for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].addEventListener('click', collapse, false);
}
```

I edited your jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/4cv220mc/5/